# Como gerar "unescape" dentro de código

Tags: javascript, html, criptografia

Tenho um criptografador simples de unescape e gostaria que o encode gerado ficasse dentro do código padrão do unescape, tipo:

código que eu uso:

```
var encN=1;

  function decodeTxt(s){
  var s1=unescape(s.substr(0,s.length-1));
  var t='';
  for(i=0;i<s1.length;i++)t+=String.fromCharCode(s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length-1,1));
  return unescape(t);
        }

  function encodeTxt(s){
  s=escape(s);
  var ta=new Array();
  for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)ta[i]=s.charCodeAt(i)+encN;
  return ""+escape(eval("String.fromCharCode("+ta+")"))+encN;
  }

  function escapeTxt(os){
  var ns='';
  var t;
  var chr='';
  var cc='';
  var tn='';
  for(i=0;i<256;i++){
  tn=i.toString(16);
  if(tn.length<2)tn="0"+tn;
  cc+=tn;
  chr+=unescape('%'+tn);
  }
  cc=cc.toUpperCase();
  os.replace(String.fromCharCode(13)+'',"%13");
  for(q=0;q<os.length;q++){
  t=os.substr(q,1);
  for(i=0;i<chr.length;i++){
  if(t==chr.substr(i,1)){
  t=t.replace(chr.substr(i,1),"%"+cc.substr(i*2,2));
  i=chr.length;
  }}
  ns+=t;
  }
  return ns;
  }
  function unescapeTxt(s){
  return unescape(s);
  }
  function wF(s){
  document.write(decodeTxt(s));
  }
```

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <form name="fA">
<div id="casa">
          <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="document.fA.c1.value=escapeTxt(document.fA.f1.value)"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <br/>

          <textarea id="f1" cols=50 rows=10 wrap="off"></textarea>

</div>
<div id="casa2">
          <input type="button" value="Decode" onclick="document.fA.f1.value=unescapeTxt(document.fA.c1.value)">
          <br>
          <textarea id="c1" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>

</div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Porém, queria que o código gerado aparecesse junto com o código abaixo:

```
<script language='javascript'>
document.write( unescape( 'CODIGO GERADO AQUI' ) );
</script>
```

na hora que gerar o código ja sai tudo e nao só o encode sem script...

Comment: é apenas de códigos html

Comment: Tá, e o que você quer exatamente que aconteca, que atualmente não acontece? e qual a dificuldade que está tendo pra fazer o que quer? Essas coisas já tem que fazer parte da pergunta, senão fica complicado. Note que não é falta de vontade de ajudar, mas é que se toda pergunta o pessoal tiver que ficar tentando endender o problema, atrapalha o lado de quem ajuda e o seu. Fica a sugestão de dar uma lida em [ask], e depois [edit] a pergunta com o maior de clareza possível.

Comment: na hora de gerar o código, gerasse dentro do script, pronto pra copiar após gerar porque se não eu tenho que pegar o código gerado e colocar manualmente dentro do script <script language='javascript'>
document.write( unescape( 'código gerado ficaria aqui' ) );
</script>

Comment: Nesse caso não é só incluir o código na hora de dar o escape?

Comment: nao se incluir o codigo o mesmo ficará encodado...

Comment: exato, e será "desencodado" ué.

Comment: você nao entendeu, tipo vo encodar qualquer tipo de html e usa-los encodados no javascript unescape, se eu colocar o código javascript na hora de encodar vai encodar tudo e eu teria que colocar o codigo javascript do mesmo jeito entendeu, eu só quero que já saia gerado com o javascript...

Comment: Não precisa colocar dentro do encode né... você concatena depois de codificado. Na verdade eu acho legal isso aí que vc tá fazendo como exercicio apenas, pq nao serve pra nada, mas aí já é vc que tem que ver onde investe o tempo. De qq forma, bastaria por o código dentro da função encode, como string, antes do retorno.

Comment: eu uso esse tipo de código desde 2009 até hoje uso, então se não pode ou não consegue me ajudar, não diga que não vou precisar do código, porque se eu to fazendo a pergunta no site é por que eu preciso.

Comment: Bom, eu tou avisando e perdendo meu tempo aqui pra te ajudar, já praticamente disse a solução, mas se você está tão certo assim que eu estou enganado, vou me ocupar com outra coisa então. De qq forma, boa sorte e boa noite.

Comment: "bastaria por o código dentro da função encode, como string, antes do retorno" parece simples pra quem entende...
se eu soubesse fazer não estaria aqui né kkkk, mas boa noite msm assim e desculpa por fazer vc perder seu precioso tempo...

Comment: Foi só uma orientação de como fazer, quem sabe mais tarde alguém dá um exemplo numa resposta oficial. Quanto ao fato de dizer que o código não tem muita serventia é que na prática qualquer um decodifica os dados com facilidade, então não compensa o tempo que você gasta com esse tipo de coisa, e ainda acaba atrapalhando a indexação do conteúdo. Mas o código é seu, vc tem todo o direito de fazer como quiser, só acho importante você saber.

Comment: Ta bom, cada um tem sua opnião né, e como você disse ta gastando seu tempo aqui atoa, não quero discutir com ninguém e nem saber se é bom ou ruim o código, apenas quero a solução para a minha pergunta se possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui, apesar de não ser o mesmo código mas pra mim já está bom:

```
var encN=1;

// ENCODES, IN UNICODE FORMAT, ALL TEXT AND THEN ESCAPES THE OUTPUT
function encodeTxt(s){
s=escape(s);
var ta=new Array();
for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)ta[i]=s.charCodeAt(i)+encN;
return ""+escape(eval("String.fromCharCode("+ta+")"))+encN;
}


// WRITES THE DECODED OUTPUT, ALONG WITH THE ESCAPED DECODER FUNCTION TO THE DIV
function writeOut(){
document.forms["fa"].output.value="<"+"script language='javascript'"+">document.write(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%6C%61%6E%67%75%61%67%65%3D%22%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%3E%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%64%46%28%73%29%7B%76%61%72%20%73%31%3D%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%73%2E%73%75%62%73%74%72%28%30%2C%73%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%2D%31%29%29%3B%20%76%61%72%20%74%3D%27%27%3B%66%6F%72%28%69%3D%30%3B%69%3C%73%31%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%3B%69%2B%2B%29%74%2B%3D%53%74%72%69%6E%67%2E%66%72%6F%6D%43%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%28%73%31%2E%63%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%41%74%28%69%29%2D%73%2E%73%75%62%73%74%72%28%73%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%2D%31%2C%31%29%29%3B%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%77%72%69%74%65%28%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%74%29%29%3B%7D%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));dF('"+encodeTxt(document.forms['fa'].f2.value)+"')<"+"/script>";
}
```

html:

```
<form name="fa">

   <textarea id="f2" cols="80" rows="15" wrap="off" class="code">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
// SAMPLE SCRIPT #1
alert('Hello World');
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="your_js_file.js">
// SAMPLE SCRIPT #2 - CALLING AN EXTERNAL JS FILE
</SCRIPT>
   </textarea>

   <br />
   <select name="et" onchange="encN=this.selectedIndex+1" class="inpS">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
   </select>

   <input type="button" class="inpB" value="Encode" onclick="writeOut()" /> 
   <input type="reset" class="inpB" value="Limpar" />
  <br />
   <textarea name="output" class="code" id="caixe" rows="15" cols="80">
Encoded output will be displayed here...
   </textarea>
</form>
```

o código gerado já sai com o javascript, vlw a todos que não souberam me ajudar e votaram negativo :)